# Programmatically add composer while creating a component

Tags: zk

I need to create a window component from a ZUML using different composers. But i cant figure out how to do this programmatically. It works fine when I apply the composer to the window within the ZUML file.

**This works**

dataTemplate.zul

```
<window id="dataTemplateWindow"
apply="dk.dataproces.cpraap.controllers.DataTemplateWindowController">
          ....
```

Controller

```
dataTemplateWindow = (Window) Executions.createComponents(
                "dataTemplate.zul", homeWindow, null);
```

**I would like to do something like this**

No composer is attached within the ZUML, and it is instead added programmatically.

```
Map data = new HashMap();
data.put("composer","dk.dataproces.cpraap.controllers.DataTemplateWindowController");
dataTemplateWindow = (Window) Executions.createComponents("dataTemplate.zul", homeWindow, data);
```

The reason is I need to attach different controllers to the same ZUML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your almost there.

You just need to declare in the second zul that the composer comes from the arg map.

You do this in the zul by :

```
apply="${arg.composer}"
```

[Here is a test fiddle where I did it.](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2ffnrb2/64-Executions-createComponents-with-dynamic-composer)